# give each id the same column value R

Tags: r

I want to give each unique id the same column value for first.date based on their first.date for fruit=='apple'.

This is what I have:

```
 names      dates  fruit first.date
1   john 2010-07-01   kiwi       <NA>
2   john 2010-09-01  apple 2010-09-01
3   john 2010-11-01 banana       <NA>
4   john 2010-12-01 orange       <NA>
5   john 2011-01-01  apple 2010-09-01
6   mary 2010-05-01 orange       <NA>
7   mary 2010-07-01  apple 2010-07-01
8   mary 2010-07-01 orange       <NA>
9   mary 2010-09-01  apple 2010-07-01
10  mary 2010-11-01  apple 2010-07-01
```

this is what I want:

```
 names      dates  fruit first.date
1   john 2010-07-01   kiwi 2010-09-01
2   john 2010-09-01  apple 2010-09-01
3   john 2010-11-01 banana 2010-09-01
4   john 2010-12-01 orange 2010-09-01
5   john 2011-01-01  apple 2010-09-01
6   mary 2010-05-01 orange 2010-07-01
7   mary 2010-07-01  apple 2010-07-01
8   mary 2010-07-01 orange 2010-07-01
9   mary 2010-09-01  apple 2010-07-01
10  mary 2010-11-01  apple 2010-07-01
```

This is my disastrous attempt:

```
getdates$first.date[is.na]<-getdates[getdates$first.date & getdates$fruit=='apple',]
```

Thank you in advance

**reproducible DF**

```
names<-as.character(c("john", "john", "john", "john", "john", "mary", "mary","mary","mary","mary"))
dates<-as.Date(c("2010-07-01",  "2010-09-01", "2010-11-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-01-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-01",  "2010-09-01",  "2010-11-01"))
fruit<-as.character(c("kiwi","apple","banana","orange","apple","orange","apple","orange", "apple", "apple")) 
first.date<-as.Date(c(NA, "2010-09-01",NA,NA, "2010-09-01", NA, "2010-07-01", NA, "2010-07-01","2010-07-01"))
getdates<-data.frame(names,dates,fruit, first.date)
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. One can't read anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to do when there are duplicate entries for `first.date` and `apple` (for a given name), this will just take the first one:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(getdates)

dt[, first.date := first.date[fruit == 'apple'][1], by = names]
dt
#    names      dates  fruit first.date
# 1:  john 2010-07-01   kiwi 2010-09-01
# 2:  john 2010-09-01  apple 2010-09-01
# 3:  john 2010-11-01 banana 2010-09-01
# 4:  john 2010-12-01 orange 2010-09-01
# 5:  john 2011-01-01  apple 2010-09-01
# 6:  mary 2010-05-01 orange 2010-07-01
# 7:  mary 2010-07-01  apple 2010-07-01
# 8:  mary 2010-07-01 orange 2010-07-01
# 9:  mary 2010-09-01  apple 2010-07-01
#10:  mary 2010-11-01  apple 2010-07-01
```

Comment: Hi eddi - the first.date value is the first time a person ever got an apple, the duplicate ensures that this first date does not get overridden by the next date they get an apple. your code seems to work very well as it will do what I want: fill a column with the first date for apples per id. Thank you!

Comment: If there are multiple groups and lots of entries per group, this *may* have poor performance because of vector scan per group. Maybe this is better: `DT <- data.table(getdates); setkey(DT, names, fruit); dd <- DT[J(unique(names), "apple"), mult="first"]$dates; DT[, first.date := dd[.GRP], by=names]`. That is, if the OP doesn't mind reordering of rows.

Comment: Hi Arun, i will have about 6,000 individual people with at least 18 rows each... so your approach may have benefits. Will try it out and report back. Thank you

Comment: @user2363642, I don't think this (the one I wrote) will be faster for the data dimensions you mention... It's better to benchmark anyways :).