# picking first date for each individual R

Tags: r, data.table, col, subject

This question is related to this post [give each id the same column value R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687547/give-each-id-the-same-column-value-r) butthe solution there is not working for me.

I have a datatable where index is the first date that an individual got a drug C10.*? in the period between 2010-04-01 and 2010-09-30:

```
names   drugs      dates      index
1:  mary C10AA07 2009-10-01         NA
2:  mary C09AA03 2010-06-01         NA
3:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-01 2010-07-01
4:  mary A02BC01 2010-07-01         NA
5:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-24 2010-07-01
6:   tom C10AA05 2009-12-01         NA
7:   tom C10AA05 2010-04-06 2010-04-06
8:   tom C07AB03 2010-05-12         NA
9:   tom C10AA05 2010-08-01 2010-04-06
```

I am trying to give mary her index date for all rows in the column 'index'. and similarly for tom. so that the ouput is like this:

```
 names   drugs      dates      index
1:  mary C10AA07 2009-10-01 2010-07-01
2:  mary C09AA03 2010-06-01 2010-07-01
3:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-01 2010-07-01
4:  mary A02BC01 2010-07-01 2010-07-01
5:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-24 2010-07-01
6:   tom C10AA05 2009-12-01 2010-04-06
7:   tom C10AA05 2010-04-06 2010-04-06
8:   tom C07AB03 2010-05-12 2010-04-06
9:   tom C10AA05 2010-08-01 2010-04-06
```

this is exactly what the problem is in the link posted above. These are the lines of code I have tried, but each code gives me pack just all NA values for index or else doesnt change my dt2

Attempt 1:

```
dt2[, index := index[grepl('^C10.*?', as.character(dt2$drugs))& dt2$dates>="2010-04-01" & dt2$dates<"2010-10-01"][1], by = names]     
dt2
```

attempt 2:

```
dt2[, index := index[grepl('^C10.*?', as.character(dt2$drugs))[1], by = names])
dt2
```

I can't understand whats happening and why the code won't work. If anyone can shed any light on this that would be great. Thank you.

attempt 3:

```
dt2[, index := index[drugs == 'C10AA05' & drugs=='C10AA07'][1], by = names]
dt2
```

Comment: try `dt2[, sapply(.SD, class)]`, what do you get?

Comment: both dates and index are set up as dates.      names    drugs    dates    index 
"factor" "factor"   "Date"   "Date"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By what you are describing, if your index is not yet filled, use this:

```
dt2[, index := min(dates[grepl("^C10", drugs)], na.rm=TRUE), by=names]
```

If your index already has the correct value, and you are simply trying to fill the NA's, use the following instead, as it will be faster

```
> dt2[, index := index[!is.na(index)][[1]], by=names]
> dt2
   names   drugs      dates      index
1:  mary C10AA07 2009-10-01 2010-07-01
2:  mary C09AA03 2010-06-01 2010-07-01
3:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-01 2010-07-01
4:  mary A02BC01 2010-07-01 2010-07-01
5:  mary C10AA07 2010-07-24 2010-07-01
6:   tom C10AA05 2009-12-01 2010-04-06
7:   tom C10AA05 2010-04-06 2010-04-06
8:   tom C07AB03 2010-05-12 2010-04-06
9:   tom C10AA05 2010-08-01 2010-04-06
>
```

---

If you are going to be doing this often, I would recommend setting key to `drugs` or even creating a new column with the drugid. Note that you can use the key in `.SD`, so the following would work for you:

```
dt2[, drugid := substr(drugs, 1, 3)]
setkey(dt2, drugid)

## HAVE A LOOK AT THE OUTPUT
dt2[, .SD[.("C10"), min(dates)]]
dt2[, .SD[.("C10"), min(dates)], by=names]
dt2[, .SD[.("C10"), min(dates)]$V1, by=names]
dt2[, index := .SD[.("C10"), min(dates)]$V1, by=names]
```

Comment: yes that works. Thank you so much. Do you know why the code I tried above didn't work? My first inclination would be to say it's got something to do with NA values, but in the example i gave the link to there are na values and teh code worked fine. Just trying to learn and understand :)

Comment: @user2363642, it looks like you were using `and (&)` when you should have been using `or (|)`.   Simple mistake

Comment: @user2363642, as a general trouble shooting tip, when you are not getting results you would expect, break it down and see if each segment is giving you the pieces you would expect.  For example, in `attempt3`, I would pare it down to `dt2[, drugs == 'C10AA05' & drugs=='C10AA07', by = names]` and look at that output

Comment: thank you for the teaching points. Much appreciated. I tried changing my code to accomodate | instead of &, but it didn't make any difference. In addition, some of my code didn't use a & sign..... puzzling. As for breaking down code - thanks, good tip!

Comment: I think you are just getting mixed up in the boolean logic.  Not all of your `&` need to change, just some of them.  ie, something like `grep(..) & (date == A | date == B)`